# prevent creating a user if their password matches a value in a text file

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

When a user submits the registration form to Flask, I want to check the password they chose against a file with 10000 common passwords. If their password matches a common value, I want to flash a message instead of create the user.

I wrote the code below, but it always creates the user even if they enter one of the common passwords. What is wrong with the check I wrote?

```py
@bp.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data)
    
        with open("VanligePassord.txt") as f:
            for line in f:
                if form.password.data == line[:-1]:
                    flash("Passordet ditt er for svakt")
                else:
                    user.set_password(form.password.data)
                    db.session.add(user)
                    db.session.commit()
                    return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))
    
    return render_template("auth/register.html", form=form)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check you wrote doesn't stop when it encounters a bad password, it only flashes a message, then continues on to the next value. And if the password doesn't match the bad value, it goes to the `else` branch and gets committed immediately, regardless of if some other value were to match later.

Use `any()` to check if any value matches the password, then flash an error or commit based on that.

```py
password = form.password.data

with current_app.open_resource("common_passwords.txt") as f:
    common_values = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in f]

if any(value == password for value in common_values):
    flash("Don't use a common password.")
else:
    user.set_password(password)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```

Since you're using WTForms, you could also write this as part of the form validation instead of part of the view.

```py
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    ...

    def validate_password(self, field, data):
       with current_app.open_resource("common_passwords.txt") as f:
           common_values = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in f] 

       if any(value == data for value in common_values):
           raise ValidationError("Don't use a common password.")
```